# The remote connection was not made because the attempted VPN tunnels failed

Tags: vpn, windows-server-2016

I installed "Routing and Remote Access" role on Windows Server 2016 so I can use it as a VPN and NAT server .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uHtJ.png) On the screenshot you can see what my lab looks like. There is a ping between the server and the host. The test account is locally created on the the Server and the remote access is allowed for it. The corresponding services are up and running.

On trying to connect to the VPN gateway I got "*The remote connection was not made because the attempted VPN tunnels failed*" error message. I taught its firewall thing so I turned it off on both ends but there was no change. Server Manager is fluted with below event:

"*Failed to apply IP Security on port VPN3-74 because of error: A certificate could not be found.  Connections that use the L2TP protocol over IPSec require the installation of a machine certificate, also known as a computer certificate..  No calls will be accepted to this port.*"

The tutorial I closely followed for the configuration does not includes certificate installation so I`m very surprise to see it.

At that point I don't know how to move forward. May I ask you for help to establish the connection?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpOf3.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apku2.png)

Comment: well, maybe look for a better tutorial? the error message pretty much tells you what to look for :)

Comment: do you have any idea how to install the required certificate?

Comment: 5th hit on google: https://supporthost.in/how-to-configure-sstp-vpn-on-windows-server-2019/
Does this look like what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Let's me check if it`s applicable to my problem.

Comment: @MoWo I believe we are not on the same page. I`m not trying to configure SSTP VPN.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/apku2.png

Comment: please have a look at the link

Comment: Hi guys, I really need help. I`m traying to connect to VPN with no success for the past few days. After so many hours troubleshooting I`m steel in the meddle of no whare. I deleted everything and started from scratch.  Here are the steps I folled:

Comment: Hi guys, I really need help. I`m traying to connect to VPN with no success for the past few days. After so many hours of troubleshooting I`m still in the meddle of no whare. I deleted everything and started from scratch.  Here are the steps I fallowed: https://howto.hyonix.com/article/how-to-set-up-a-pptp-l2tp-vpn-on-windows-server/ .  No mather what I try the I always get "the remote connection was not made because the attempted vp tunnels failed" err message.

Comment: Just open your own question for it and post all the config files and error messages you are getting... It's impossible to answer like this...

Answer (score 0):

I found a failure code 720 in the event viewer of the host. I researched it and  found out that the problem is coming form the WAN mini ports. After  reinstalling them the VPN is working buttery smooth. Thank you MoWO. You made me turn on my brine and use it to search the error message.